# fx.convert not working with Money.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using chrome's Developer Tool, I can see that my index.xhtml is showing Status 200 OK
Yet when I click my Convert button the converted amount is not displayed.
Here is my xhtml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Currency Exchange Rate Calculator</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="money.js"></script>
        <script src="accounting.js"></script>
        <script src="http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=e6b775e4bbde4ae19dd7294c39d71b15"></script>
        <script src="http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json?app_id=e6b775e4bbde4ae19dd7294c39d71b15"></script>
        <script src="http://openexchangerates.org/api/historical/2011-10-18.json?app_id=e6b775e4bbde4ae19dd7294c39d71b15"></script>
        <link rel="StyleSheet"  type="text/css"  href="apricot.css"></link>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Load exchange rates data via the cross-domain/AJAX proxy:
            $(document).ready(function () {
            function load(){
                $.getJSON(
                'http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json?app_id=e6b775e4bbde4ae19dd7294c39d71b15',
                function(data) {
                    // Check money.js has finished loading:
                    if ( typeof fx != "undefined") {
                        fx.rates = data.rates;
                        fx.base = data.base;
                        alert("fx loaded");
                    } else {
                        // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
                        alert("fx not loaded");
                        var fxSetup = {
                            rates : data.rates,
                            base : data.base
                        }
                    }
                }
            ).error(function(error){console.log(error);});
                return false;    
            }
});
            function convert(){
                //load();
                var fromelement = document.getElementById('xrate:fromcur');
                var from=fromelement.value;
                var toelement = document.getElementById('xrate:tocur');
                var to = toelement.value;
                var amtelement =document.getElementById('xrate:amt');
                var amt = amtelement.value;
                alert("from = "+from+" to = "+to+" amount = "+amt);

                //fx.settings = { from: from, to: to };
                var conv=fx.convert(amt,{ from: from, to: to });
                alert("conv = "+conv);
                //fx.settings = { from: from, to: to };
                //var conv=fx.convert(amt); // 647.71034
                var convelement = document.getElementById('xrate:result');
                convelement.value=conv;

            }

        </script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="welcome">
            <h:form id="xrate">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="background-color: yellow">

                    <h:outputLabel value="Select Currency From" for="fromcur" />
                    <h:selectOneListbox  id="fromcur" size = "1" value="xxx" title="xxx" >
                        <f:selectItem id="si0" itemLabel=" " itemValue=" " />
                        <f:selectItem id="si1" itemLabel="RON" itemValue="RON" />
                        <f:selectItem id="si2" itemLabel="EUR" itemValue="EUR" />
                        <f:selectItem id="si3" itemLabel="CAD" itemValue="CAD" />
                        <f:selectItem id="si4" itemLabel="GBP" itemValue="GBP" />
                        <f:selectItem id="si5" itemLabel="USD" itemValue="USD" />
                        <f:selectItem id="si6" itemLabel="MXP" itemValue="MXP" />
                        <f:selectItem id="si7" itemLabel="CNY" itemValue="CNY" />
                    </h:selectOneListbox>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Select Currency To" for="tocur" />
                    <h:selectOneListbox  id="tocur" size = "1" value="xxx" title="xxx" >
                        <f:selectItem id="ti0" itemLabel=" " itemValue=" " />
                        <f:selectItem id="ti1" itemLabel="RON" itemValue="RON" />
                        <f:selectItem id="ti2" itemLabel="EUR" itemValue="EUR" />
                        <f:selectItem id="ti3" itemLabel="CAD" itemValue="CAD" />
                        <f:selectItem id="ti4" itemLabel="GBP" itemValue="GBP" />
                        <f:selectItem id="ti5" itemLabel="USD" itemValue="USD" />
                        <f:selectItem id="ti6" itemLabel="MXP" itemValue="MXP" />
                        <f:selectItem id="ti7" itemLabel="CNY" itemValue="CNY" />

                    </h:selectOneListbox>

                    <h:outputLabel value="Enter Amount" for="amt" />
                    <h:inputText id="amt"   style="color:red;background-                      color:yellowgreen" size="10"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Calculate" id="calc" onclick="convert()"/>
                    <h:outputText id ="result"  style="color:blue;border:5px solid tan;" />

                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>

enter code here
```

I am using a link to openexchangerates.org
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error in the code.
So for anyone that is interested this works fine now:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
        // Load exchange rates data via the cross-domain/AJAX proxy:
        //           $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON(
        'http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json?app_id=e6b775e4bbde4ae19dd7294c39d71b15',
        function(data) {
            // Check money.js has finished loading:
            if ( typeof fx != "undefined") {
                fx.rates = data.rates;
                fx.base = data.base;
                //alert("fx loaded");
            } else {
                // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
                //alert("fx not loaded");
                var fxSetup = {
                    rates : data.rates,
                    base : data.base
                }
            }
        }
    )


        //           });
        function convert(){
            //load();
            var fromelement = document.getElementById('xrate:fromcur');
            var from=fromelement.value;
            var toelement = document.getElementById('xrate:tocur');
            var to = toelement.value;
            var amtelement =document.getElementById('xrate:amt');
            var amt = amtelement.value;
            alert("from = "+from+" to = "+to+" amount = "+amt);

            //fx.settings = { from: from, to: to };
            var conv=fx.convert(amt,{ from: from, to: to });
            alert("conv = "+conv);
            //fx.settings = { from: from, to: to };
            //var conv=fx.convert(amt); // 647.71034
            var convelement = document.getElementById('xrate:result');
            convelement.value=conv;
            //document.getElementById('xrate:result').value=conv;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

import fx from money //React Component

```
handleSubmit(){
        /*require(["money"], function(fx) {
            console.log(fx.convert(1000, {from: "GBP", to: "HKD"}))
        })*/
        fx.base = "USD";
        fx.rates = {
            "EUR" : 0.745101, // eg. 1 USD === 0.745101 EUR
            "GBP" : 0.647710, // etc...
            "USD" : 1,        // always include the base rate (1:1)
            /* etc */
        }
        console.log(fx(1.99).from("USD").to("GBP"))
    }
```